# Setting Up a Default Server On Eclipse

Tags: php

A very simple question - in the Eclipse documenation it says, at various places, that there is a default server installed along with eclipse yet I can't find any further documentation or details. 
So is there a default server installed?

Answer (score 0):

There is a default server, but I don't know if it's installed, remeber that you need to have it installed already(Tomcat, Apache...).

You can add a default server, see this links:

- [Setting a default server](http://help.eclipse.org/help32/index.jsp?topic=/org.eclipse.wst.server.ui.doc.user/topics/twprefin.html)
- [Building and Running a Web Application](http://www.eclipse.org/webtools/community/tutorials/BuildJ2EEWebApp/BuildJ2EEWebApp.html)

Answer (score 0):

I believe it means you can set a default server, and has configurations applicable for many different ones.

Try Apache Tomcat.